# Locating slow code in Laravel

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-4, benchmarking

Is there a built-in way to benchmark and track down slow code in Laravel?

Or is it more effective to just do a cachegrind out?

Every page on one of the sites I just built is taking 1-2 seconds to load regardless of how simple the page is.

Comment: It Depends on your machine, the web server and amount of memory available.
I had a web app that ran slow on my computer but super-fast on a remote web server.

Comment: It's happening the same on two machines (local dev and cloud production) that are very fast setups.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The laravel-debugbar package is a really great tool to figure out what is causing your slow load times.

It can be added by adding:

```
"barryvdh/laravel-debugbar": "dev-master",
```

To your composer.josn file then:

```
'Barryvdh\Debugbar\ServiceProvider',
```

as a ServiceProvider in app/config/app.php

Then you can publish it using artisan (only to the environment you want to run tests on).

```
php artisan debugbar:publish
```

You can find better instructions on their github page [here](https://github.com/barryvdh/laravel-debugbar).

Thank you for the suggestion! Here are a few screenshots of the debugbar:

[image]
[image: Display of queries that were run]

Comment: Thank you for the suggestion!  I just uploaded a few screenhots.

Comment: That's pretty sweet looking. I love how Laravel packages manage to keep it classy. :)

Comment: It might be useful to compare what laravel provides for identifying problems like this to [other frameworks](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23639761/why-so-long-request-time-for-admin-panel-in-croogo-cakephp) - not to enter some kind of holy war but for those willing to improve what Laravel has to be as or more useful (maybe it just needs more timer integration). Alternatively xdebug profiling will offer _much_ more granularity than 2 data points. It's not much use to see that the bit of the request that was slow was "all of it" :)

Answer (score 3):

Another solution which I use is Clockwork. Give it a try, I think you'll like it.

https://github.com/itsgoingd/clockwork

Comment: Very nice! I love that it is tied to a Chrome extension.

Comment: Yeah, it's really useful. Use it all the time.

Answer (score 0):

Right, clockwork is good, it gives all required information.
You can use browser extension https://github.com/itsgoingd/clockwork-chrome or cli application https://github.com/ptrofimov/clockwork-cli