# Why so long request time for admin panel in Croogo/CakePHP?

Tags: cakephp, croogo

I don't understand why I have so long request time for admin panel in Croogo CMS.

Printscreen for home administration panel (debug kit plugin):
[image: my timer log]

How can I check what exactly causes that as long the page loads? Page view contains few elements, but loaded more than 4 seconds.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: The waterfall timeline shows that the time is spent in the navigation element (affecting the "parent" timer events admin layout and "Rendering View")

Answer (score 1):

It seems to be taking the longest time in rendering the admin menus.

I've also experienced this and wrote a patch to cache the results.  Replace `Plugin/Croogo/View/Elements/admin/navigation.ctp` with the following:

```
<nav class="navbar-inverse sidebar">
    <div class="navbar-inner">
    <?php
        $cacheKey = 'adminnav_' . $this->Layout->getRoleId() . '_' . $this->request->url . '_' . md5(serialize($this->request->query));
        $navItems = Cache::read($cacheKey, 'croogo_menus');
        if ($navItems === false) {
            $navItems = $this->Croogo->adminMenus(CroogoNav::items(), array(
                'htmlAttributes' => array(
                    'id' => 'sidebar-menu',
                ),
            ));
            Cache::write($cacheKey, $navItems, 'croogo_menus');
        }
        echo $navItems;
    ?>
    </div>
</nav>
```